# implementing chop() using iterators

Tags: python, iterator

Current version:

```
def chop(ar,size):
    p=len(ar)/size
    for i in xrange(p):
        yield ar[(i*size):((i+1)*size)]
```

ar is type of list().

What i want is that chop() takes iterator and return iterator.

```
for i in chop(xrange(9),3):
    for j in i:
       print j,
    print
```

prints

```
0 1 2
3 4 5
6 7 8
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an implementation in the [`itertools` documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html):

```
def grouper(n, iterable, fillvalue=None):
    "grouper(3, 'ABCDEFG', 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx"
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return izip_longest(fillvalue=fillvalue, *args)
```

Comment: That's a really clever implementation.  Guess that's why it's in the documentation.  Though I think it's slightly too clever.  It needs a comment explaining how izip and the multiple pointers to the same iterator interact.

Comment: @Omnifarious: I find that to be true of a lot of the examples in the `itertools` documentation (i.e. too clever). But I think thinking through it is a good exercise for understanding how you can do interesting things with iterators efficiently.

Comment: I did not came that far in doc :D Thanks

Comment: @Omnifarious, This answer appears many times over on SO already. I think it is idiomatic Python by now :)